# New-Object doesn't instantiate SMO

Tags: sql-server, powershell, oledb

Why does this work:

```
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDB.OleDbCommand
```

and why doesn't this:

```
$sql = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO
```

How do I know which classes need this "special" treatment?

Comment: I'll assume that it is not just that you misspelt `SqlServer`?

Comment: no, sorry, I've just misspelt...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what actually happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

[SMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx) isn't a class, it's a namespace. You need to instantiate an object in the namespace. For instance, if you wanted a server, you'd do:

```
$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "yourServer";
```

Comment: Hi Ben,
thanks. Following your advice I get:
new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]: make sure the assembly containing this type is 
loaded.
It means: some assemblies are immediately loaded, some not.
The perfect chaos: using PS 3.0 and: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') is deprecated: What should I use now?
Purclot

Comment: `Add-Type` is the "new" way to load assemblies, however for SMO it will often cause errors because it tries to load the wrong assembly. When using `Add-Type` you should specify the path to get the correct version. See http://www.maxtblog.com/2011/07/sql-server-smo-loading-assemblies-gotcha%E2%80%99s/ .  Personally, I still use `LoadWithPartialName()`. It still works in PS v4 and it will take some time until the systems in my network uses a powershell or .net version where this is not supported anymore. :)

Comment: The easiest way I've found is to start sqlps that comes with your sql server install. And by "easiest", I mean "you don't have to do anything since it loads the module for you".